# Redefine a variable inside a merge request in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is there a way to redefine a CI variable inside a merge request? Or maybe there can be a different solution. Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

We have a bunch of microservices. Some of them depend on the other microservices. When developing a feature, we usually link the services to a staging instance of the sub-service that is built from a develop branch. In such a case I just use a variable on a project or on a group level (e.g. `SUB_SERVICE_URL`). However, sometimes we develop a feature that requires changes in multiple projects at once. And in such a case I need to link one review app to another review app instead of linking it to the staging version. If I could override `SUB_SERVICE_URL` on the merge request level, this would solve the problem. But is it possible? If not, what would be the alternative solutions?

Comment: That would essentially be the same as checking out the branch and changing the variable yourself, no?

Comment: Em... nope. Look, you can re-define the variables when running the pipelines manually or scheduled. Why can't a merge request have this? Any objective arguments against it?

Comment: Ah my mistake, I didn't realize you meant CI variable

Comment: Trying to figure this out as well. The closest I have seen is the concept of [push options](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html); however, I haven't been able to get it to work (maybe broken?; [gitlab-org/gitlab!341715](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/341715).

Comment: Is there a solution now?